# Difficulty in retrieving the tweets with geocode(lat&long) & plotting it in map.

Tags: r, twitter, geocode

I've some difficulty in attaining the below.

If you've any idea to recover from this problem, would be much helpful.

The major problem now I'm facing is that Twitter search API retrieves only very very limited tweets  with geocode(lat,long) enabled.

This task is the Visualisation of tweets I used for sentiment analysis. So if I've used 1500 tweets to analyse sentiments, I couldn't retrieve even 100 whole tweets with lat&long for the same keyword. Even with those 100 retrieved tweets most of them are NA, so finally when I visualize I get only handful of plots of tweets say 4 location of tweets. That's not at all enough for my demonstration of my project.

Getting frustrated with this problem.

Is there any other better alternative to accomplish what I need?

Comment: Perhaps you could collect tweets over a few hours/days/weeks, and only store those tweets with lat/long. I was able to collect about 25 tweets within 50 miles of my home within a few minutes: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/alexwoolford/streamingNearbyTweets/blob/master/streamingNearbyTweets.ipynb

Comment: I think what you have experienced is pretty normal. Based on my experience, if you have 10% of total tweets with lon/lat, that is pretty good. All you can do is to collect tweets with a long span as Alex suggested; you need patience. Since Twitter users can choose not to show lon/lat, you cannot do anything about this, can you?

Comment: Pay for [Gnip](https://gnip.com/historical/historical-powertrack/), which claims to give you access to historic tweets.

Comment: Can we not fetch tweets with lat&long as much as we fetch  for sentiment analysis? Say if I fetch 1500 tweets without geocode for sentiment purpose, is it possible to fetch the same amount of tweets with geocode? By the way, the language I am working with is R. If I use lesser tweets (to plot in the map) than I use for sentiment analysis then there is no use of including this tweet viz in my project. Really annoying @AlexWoolford

Comment: I use R language. I researched GNIP site. They provide API's for languages other than R.  Even if I pay, I don't think they can provide a solution for R language @lukeA

Comment: No I cannot @jazzurro

Comment: Your code is in Python. Think it's possible to turn it into an R script. @AlexWoolford

Comment: An API is language independent. You can use R, Python or ... Turbo Pascal to query it...